# eZ Publish cannot access RSS Feed from Front office

Tags: rss, frontend, ezpublish

I have created RSS Feed in the back office of eZ publish. The problem is that I can access the RSS Feed from the admin interface of eZ Publish but **not from the Front end**.

example :

http://my-back-ez/rss/feed/news => Working

http://my-front-ez/rss/feed/news => Redirect to admin login

Instead of showing the RSS feed, i'm redirected to the admin login with the front url, I don't understand why.

Every conf seems to be initialized correclty. I've read that the routing is **managed automatically** by eZ Legacy and I do not have to create a specific route in the routing.yml file.

eZ Publish Version : 2014.11 (5.4).

**EDIT :**

When i log in via the front office there is no cookie **"is_logged_in"** so when i try to access the url "/rss/feed/myFeed/" i am redirected to admin login (probably passing throught legacy_stack) and the **"is_logged_in"** cookie is automatically created.

When i connect direclty from admin the **"is_logged_in"** cookie is created after login.

While the cookie is created i can access the RSS feed.

I've read that the **"is_logged_in"** cookie is deprecated, is it still the case here ? I am aware that RSS is a legacy module so it probably needs this cookie to verify if the user is logged.

Do i have to create manually the "is_logged_in" cookie or there is another way to allow the access to RSS feed ?

Thanks,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution !

In the site.ini.append.php file you have to set the **RequireUserLogin** to false to tell legacy stack not to look for the **is_logged_in** cookie.

[SiteAccessSettings]
RequireUserLogin=false

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate  RSS/feed function for anonymous user too. You can  do it in admin>administration>roles

Comment: I did, there s no restrictions for anonymous user in tha admin for RSS Feed.

Comment: Sorry to insist but do you have a line  that *explicitely* allows RSS/feed for anonymous user and are you sure are connected  as anonymous ? If it's the  case you may have a rewrite rule in ez or apache but it's unlikely

Comment: Yes, i have a explicit line [link](http://s21.postimg.org/oyjoce0mv/anonymous_role.jpg).
And i have tried to deactivate the rewrite rules but not working either.

Comment: This can't "right and role" problem. Because in case of "rights" problem, you don't get redirected to admin site. You'll be prompt to enter username and password in the frontend.

Comment: The situation explained in the question, to me looks like something totally un-related to rss itself

Comment: so maybe a rewrite rule, either in eZ Publish URL rewrite, or in the webserver ? What happen when you enable redirection debug ? if ezpublish stops before redirection then you could eliminate the webserver hypothesis